# When is the expectation of function times input, the expectation of derivative?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, expectation, gaussian-integral

So, my question is about the identity

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x) e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \mathrm{d}x$$

which, to me, comes down to

$$\mathbb{E}[X f(X)] = \mathbb{E}[f'(X)].$$

Now I would like to know what properties $f$ should satisfy for this identity to hold. Using integration by parts

$$\int_{-a}^a x f(x) e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-a}^a f'(x) e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \mathrm{d}x - \left(f(a) e^{\frac{-a^2}{2}} - f(-a) e^{\frac{-a^2}{2}}\right),$$

I managed to figure out that sufficient conditions would be

1. $f$ is even, i.e. $f(-x) = f(x)$
2. $f$ is bounded, i.e. $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$

but I was wondering whether there are other cases for which this identity holds.

Would anybody be able to tell me for which functions $f$ this identity holds? I would also be grateful if someone could point me to the wiki of this identity, if there would be one.

Comment: If you write $f(x)$ on the left side as $\int_{-\infty} ^{x} f'(t) \, dt$ and interchange the integrals you will get the right side. For this to work you need $f(-\infty )=0$ and Fubuni's Theorem must be applicable. Perhaps you can work a set of condition different from yours using this idea.

Comment: A better sufficient condition would be $$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\,f(x)\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)=0\,.$$  That is, $f(x)$ grows much more slowly than $\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$.  In other words, $$f(x) \in o\Biggl(\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\Biggr)\text{ as }x\to\pm\infty\,.$$  Hence, functions with polynomial or exponential growth will fit the bill.

Comment: The condition that $f$ is an even function is actually not a good criterion.  Your integral with $f(x)=\exp(x^2)$ will blow up (i.e, $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,x\,f(x)\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,\text{d}x$ does not exist).  Only when you compute the Cauchy principal value of this integral will you get $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The condition $f(-\infty) = 0$ might be troublesome for the functions I am considering.

Comment: @Batominovski That seems like a better sufficient condition indeed. Would I be correct to say that this allows almost all $f$ that are not exponential (assuming that I do not consider special, exotic or complicated functions)?

Comment: @MrTsjolder Actually the condition $f(-\infty) =0$ is not needed at all! You can write $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x} f'(t)\, dt$ and note that the left side vanishes when $f$ is a constant. Thus, only Fubini's Theorem  needs to be justified for which you just need an integrability condition.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \int xf(x) e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = \int f(x) \Big( xe^{-x^2/2}\, dx\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int u\,dv= uv-\int v\, du & & \text{(integration by parts)} \\[10pt]
= {} & f(x) e^{-x^2/2} - \int e^{-x^2/2} \Big(f'(x) \, dx\Big)
\end{align}
So you need
$$
0 = \Big[ f(x) e^{-x^2/2} \Big]_{x\,:=\,0}^{x\,:=\,+\infty} = \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) e^{-x^2/2} - \lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
You also need the integrals of the absolute values of all functions whose integrals are taken to be finite.

You certainly don't need $f$ to be even.

However, if $f'(x) = e^{x^2},$ then you have a complication: the very last integral that appears above diverges to $+\infty.$

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar enough with analysis / calculus to understand what this should tell me about sufficient conditions on $f$. Do you care to elaborate?